# How do I link to the posts page?

Tags: posts

How can I link to the posts page that has been set in Settings > Reading?

This is for a premium theme so it can't just be the page's permalink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress Does it like this this.

```
echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Well generally that is set to just your homepage? Or your blog index? I dont quite understand your question and what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes generally it is the home page but there is an option in Settings > Reading to use a static page. There you select your home page to be whichever page you'd like and the 'posts page' to be another page. It's pretty basic to be honest